# Intent setAction ACTION_SNOOZE retired?

Tags: android, android-studio, notifications

hmm, even the android developer page:

[Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification?hl=th#Updating)

shows this line in the example for notification 'snooze' code:

```html
snoozeIntent.setAction(ACTION_SNOOZE);
```

but when I try to use it in my Android Studio (3.6.1), it doesn't accept it (or offer it when asking for list of ACTION_ suggestions).

Google is not my friend here, any idea what's wrong on my side?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you do not use a predefined 'Intent.ACTION_...'. Instead you create your own constant, being a String, and retrieve this when accepting the intent with 'getAction()'.

For the official link:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#setAction(java.lang.String)

Although it does not specify such behavior explicitly, it is okay to do this. Unfortunate the guide about 'Notifications' did not expanded on this subject. However, you can see a similar behavior being done with the CHANNEL_ID oa.

As an extra:
`If you define your own actions, be sure to include your app's package name as a prefix, as shown in the following example:`
Link: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#Building